# Bizarre behaviour of pandas Series.value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas Series with numerical data and I want to find its unique values together with their frequency-appearance. I use the standard procedure

```
# Given the my_data is a column of a pd.Dataframe df
unique = df[my_data].value_counts() 
print unique
```

And here is the results that I get

```
# -------------------OUTPUT
-0.010000    46483 
-0.010000    16895
-0.027497    12215
-0.294492    11915
 0.027497    11397
```

What I don't get is **why I have the "same value" (-0.01) occurring twice**. Is that an internal threshold (small value) or is something that I am doing wrong??

**Update**

If I store the dataframe in csv and read it again I get the correct result, namely:

`# -------------------OUTPUT
 -0.010000    63378 
 -0.027497    12215
 -0.294492    11915
  0.027497    11397`

**Solution**

Based on the discussion, I found the source of the problem and the solution. As mentioned it is a floating-point precision which can be solved with rounding the values. Though, I wouldn't be able to see that without

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', repr)
```

Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: What does the dataframe `df` look like? Does it have more precision than shown in the output here?

Comment: Yes it has more precision, but even if I round it nothing changes in the output

Comment: In that case, refer to [MCVE] to provide us example data.

Comment: Create a MCV it's unfortunately not possible. Check my update if you have time

Comment: @dthed: Can you explain why it's not possible? All you need to do is cut down your dataset repeatedly until you find a minimal one that exhibits this behaviour. E.g., what happens if you take the first half of your existing dataset? What about the first half of *that*? Etc.

Comment: The problem is not the size of the dataset, but how this is obtained. The full code is something like 30k lines. As for the dataset itself, as I mentioned in my edit, as long as you store it in csv format and load it back then the problem doesn't appear anymore...

Comment: @dthed: Doesn't matter. You have the dataset already. You can cut it down as I described (no need to regenerate it each time). Once you have a minimal dataset, do a `pd.set_option('display.float_format', repr)` and then print that minimal dataset and edit the results into this question. We don't need all the code.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the above command. Very useful!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's a float precision issue similar to the following one:

```
In [1]: 0.1 + 0.2
Out[1]: 0.30000000000000004

In [2]: 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3
Out[2]: False
```

so try this:

```
df[my_data].round(6).value_counts()
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Demo:

```
In [14]: s = pd.Series([-0.01, -0.01, -0.01000000000123, 0.2])

In [15]: s
Out[15]:
0   -0.01
1   -0.01
2   -0.01
3    0.20
dtype: float64

In [16]: s.value_counts()
Out[16]:
-0.01    2
-0.01    1
 0.20    1
dtype: int64

In [17]: s.round(6).value_counts()
Out[17]:
-0.01    3
 0.20    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This was my first thought, but nothing changes even if I round the values.

Comment: @dthed, in this case we would need a small __reproducible__ data set in order to be able to help you...

Comment: Creating a MCV it's unfortunately not possible. Check my update if you have time. It seems that floating-precision **does play a role** but cannot be fixed with the rounding...

Comment: @dthed, i don't think i can help without a reproducible sample data set. Please check updated answer - there i reproduced your issue and rounding did help...

Comment: Thank you for the example and your time!